# Get custom attribute value using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm writing to an XML file from which I'm going to retrieve data later.

Here's how I'm writing to the file.

```
  XNamespace testNM = "urn:lst-emp:emp";
                XDocument xDoc;
                string path = "project_data.xml";
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    xDoc = new XDocument(
                               new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null),
                               new XElement(testNM + "Test")
                               );
                }
                else
                {
                    xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
                }

                var element = new XElement("key",
                        new XAttribute("name", key),
                        new XElement("Type", type),
                        new XElement("Value", value));

                xDoc.Element(testNM + "Test").Add(element);

                // Save to Disk
                xDoc.Save(path);
```

And this is what my XML file looks like after data is written to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Test xmlns="urn:lst-emp:emp">
  <key name="key2" xmlns="">
    <Type>int</Type>
    <Value>12312</Value>
  </key>
  <key name="key3" xmlns="">
    <Type>String</Type>
    <Value>asdfasd</Value>
  </key>
</Test>
```

Now what would be the simplest way to get the `name` attribute value (*key2* and *key3* in this case) along with the `Type` and `Value` attribute values.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Hint: look at `XElement.Attribute(XName)`. Also, please put more effort into formatting your code when posting.

Comment: I tried `XElement.Attribute(XName)` before posting but it wasn't the correct approach (as seen in the accepted answer.)

Comment: Um, the accepted answer called `keyNode.Attribute("name")` so in what way is that *not* the correct approach? If you've tried something which sounds sensible, you should say so in your question and show what it does compared with what you want it to do.

Comment: I was trying to pass `XElement.Attribute(XName)` to a string and didn't realize I needed to use a `var` or `.Value`. Will give more info on what I've tried next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the document;

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"doc.xml");
```

Loop the `key` nodes reading what you need;

```
foreach (var keyNode in doc.Root.Elements("key"))
{
    var name = keyNode.Attribute("name");
    var type = (string)keyNode.Element("Type"); // or .value to throw if there is no node
    ...
}
```